# Can we call one test case from the another test case in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, pageobjects

I am doing automation testing using Cypress with JavaScript.

I have to manage a test case for add, search and edit user. I have created a different test case for each. After adding user, I verified recent created user by searching it. I also search same user before to edit it.

In Cypress, test cases run in a sequence. My first case for 'add user', second for 'Search user' and last one for 'Edit user'. After adding it automatically perform search actions. But before edit, I have to call all functions which are used in a 'Search' test case. I am using the POM framework.

Here is the code I have written:

```
describe('User management', function(){
    it('Add user', function(){
        obj.clickOnAddUserButton()
        obj.fillDetails()
        obj.clickOnSaveButton()
    })
    it('Search user', function(){
        obj.searchName()
        obj.searchRole()
        obj.verifyName()
        obj.verifyRole()
    })
    it('Edit user', function(){
        obj.searchName()
        obj.searchRole()
        obj.verifyName()
        obj.verifyRole()
        obj.editUser()
    })
})
```

Is it possible to call `it()` from the other `it()`, like a function we call?

I tried the following solution to understand but I was fail: [Cypress - have 1 test call another test and run it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325047/cypress-have-1-test-call-another-test-and-run-it)

I also go through the following link which doesn't help me:
[How to call the common test case in other test case in protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405650/how-to-call-the-common-test-case-in-other-test-case-in-protractor)

Let give me an example what I want exactly.

```
describe('User management', function(){
    it('Add user', function(){
        obj.clickOnAddUserButton()
        obj.fillDetails()
        obj.clickOnSaveButton()
    })
    it('Search user', function(){
        obj.searchName()
        obj.searchRole()
        obj.verifyName()
        obj.verifyRole()
    })
    it('Edit user', function(){
        //Here I want to call it() instead of calling same functions here
        //i.e. it('Search user')
        obj.editUser()
    })
})
```

Comment: No, but you can just... _write a function_ the tests call. Or extract it to a [custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands).

Answer (score 4):

You can just rearrange the code you already have a little bit.

A test pattern in general is `it('test-name', callbackFunction)`.

You can't nest `it()` because the Cypress runner needs to manage those functions for things like retries and reporting results.

But you can move `callbackFunction` to make it reuseable.

```js
describe('User management', function() {
  it('Add user', function() {
    obj.clickOnAddUserButton()
    obj.fillDetails()
    obj.clickOnSaveButton()
  })

  function searchUser() {
    obj.searchName()
    obj.searchRole()
    obj.verifyName()
    obj.verifyRole()
  }

  it('Search user', searchUser)   // NOTE no calling brackets on searchUser

  it('Edit user', function() {
    searchUser()                  // NOTE using calling brackets here
    obj.editUser()
  })
})
```

---

#### Composing inside the Page Object

It's going to be tidier to compose that `searchUser()` function inside the page object itself

```js
class User {

  searchName() {...}
  searchRole() {...}
  verifyName() {...}
  verifyRole() {...}

  searchUser() {
    this.searchName()
    this.searchRole()
    this.verifyName()
    this.verifyRole()
  }
}
```

```js
describe('User management', function(){
  it('Add user', function(){
    obj.clickOnAddUserButton()
    obj.fillDetails()
    obj.clickOnSaveButton()
  })

  it('Search user', () => {
    obj.searchUser()
  })

  it('Edit user', function(){
    obj.searchUser()
    obj.editUser()
  })
})
```

---

#### Separating steps from workflows

Or one more abstraction, compose a `UserWorkflow` page object

```js
class User {
  searchName() {...}
  searchRole() {...}
  verifyName() {...}
  verifyRole() {...}
}

class UserWorkflow {

  // Various User workflows to use in tests

  constructor() {
    this.user = new User()
  }

  searchUser() {
    this.user.searchName()
    this.user.searchRole()
    this.user.verifyName()
    this.user.verifyRole()
  }
}
```